Get build definition folder in Azure DevOps
In Azure DevOps, I can organize build definitions inside folders. Is it possible to access the build definition's logical path? I'd like to copy build artifacts to a file share and have it part of the destination directory.
I checked the documentation but I couldn't find anything beyond Build.DefinitionName which doesn't include the path I expected it to.
eg. I have a build definition called ConsoleApp inside a Utilities folder. Within the build definition, there is a copy task which copies the build output to //networkstore.local/Builds/$(Build.DefinitionName)/$(Build.BuildNumber). This returns a path of .../Builds/ConsoleApp/1 but I want .../Builds/Utilities/ConsoleApp/1.
I realize I could hardcode the path into the copy task, but it wouldn't update if the build definition was moved/cloned elsewhere/etc.

As mentioned in my answer below, you can use the Azure DevOps CLI "az pipelines build definition show" to get the name  of folder where the build definition is in, and then use the logging command 'SetVariable' to set the folder name as a pipeline variable so that you can pass the value to the subsequent steps. @ArthurConde

There is no predefined variable to get the folder of the build definition.
You can use the Azure CLI "az pipelines build definition show" with the '--query' option to get the folder name (\\Utilities). Asn use the logging command 'SetVariable' to set the folder name as the value of a pipeline variable.
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Get Build'
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN | az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/myOrg
          folderName=$(az pipelines build definition show -p myProject --id $(System.DefinitionId) --query "path" | sed 's/\\//g')
          echo $folderName
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderName;]$folderName"
    
    - bash: echo $(folderName)
      displayName: 'Show folder name'
    
    # On the susequent copy task, you can set the output path as "//networkstore.local/Builds/$(folderName)/$(Build.DefinitionName)/$(Build.BuildNumber)"



@ArthurConde, Have you tried the Azure DevOps CLI "az pipelines build definition show" and the logging command 'SetVariable' in your pipeline like as above shared? Does it work for you?
